# .mp4 to .wav conversion in python taking too longer time

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, timeout, wav, google-speech-to-text-api

I have to use the library to convert the .mp4 to .wav for fetching the transcription using google's speech to text API. But it is taking approx 5 minutes to convert a 40 MB file. I have tried moviepy and other libraries for the same. Please suggest what to use.

Comment: Share your code buddy, show us what you have tried and where you are getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

@PrathameshDoke

we are not getting the error. Just the time taken in conversion is too longer. The code we are using is following

import moviepy.editor as mp

from moviepy.editor import *  # Quick and dirty

from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip

clip = VideoFileClip("trim.5F346E8F-3677-45FF-A1DB-C002F0F07CC1.MOV")

clip.audio.write_audiofile("theaudio.wav")